# Setting up multiple Tor hidden services on Lighttpd Raspian

Tags: lighttpd

I have exhausted the google links and still can't get it to work. I can get one host working by using [this tutorial](https://tecadmin.net/setup-virtualhosts-in-lighttpd-server/), but restarting gave an error and only the first site was visible. Ive tried adding multiple

$HTTP["host"] == "xxxxxxxxxx.onion" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/html/pages/" 
}

entries but this causes another system error and lighttpd won't restart.

I'm a noob when it comes to setting up servers, so if you know how to do it please assume I know nothing when writing your reply!

Thanks

Comment: I forgot to mention, if I use just one instance of "$HTTP["host"] == "xxxxxxxxxx.onion" { server.document-root = "/var/www/html/pages/" }" the site works.